# how to add custom ribbon button on meeting/appointment window in microsoft outlook 2013,2016

Tags: c#, wpf, vsto, outlook-addin

need to add ribbon button on highlighted place(button 1 and button 2) in the appointment/meeting screen(see the link for image) of outlook near the Alldayevent checkbox?

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mg8r.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry...not allowed to share.

Answer (score 0):

That area is not customizable, at least not using any public Outlook API.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I have seen other apps custom button in this section. e.g. Zoom Rooms - they have done this. Please check this image for reference - https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/article_attachments/209244006/Screen_Shot_2016-10-19_at_7.22.38_PM.png

Comment: There is no officially supported public API, but you can certainly try to find the window handle of that area using FindChildWindow etc. and add your control using raw Windows level API.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom UI to the ribbon only. The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Also, you may consider creating a form under the ribbon/subject field on your own subclassing Outlook windows. Read more about that on the [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) page.

FYI Add-in Express provides the `TopSubPane` layout out of the box which allows placing like shown on the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This solution is not helpful. WEBexoutlook and ZoomX outlook plugin plugin provides this kind of functionality.

Comment: The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box.

Comment: You are free to Windows API functions for subclassing Outlook windows. Also you may consider replacing the inspector UI with your own form, see the ReplacementAll layout of Outlook form regions.

Comment: Hi @EugeneAstafiev, there is something definitely. See this https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/article_attachments/209244006/Screen_Shot_2016-10-19_at_7.22.38_PM.png

They have done it.